# Trying to get GPS data on Android phone

Tags: android, gps

I am new to Android programming and am stuck. In my program I am trying to access the gps and display the latitude, longitude, etc in textviews. When I run my code on the computer using an emulator and a telnet connection, I am able to see data displayed on the emulator. However, when I run this program on an Android device (HTC ADR6300 phone), all my textviews are empty and no data is displayed. I only see the labels, but no data. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Your help is appreciated

Here is MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tvLong;
    TextView tvLat;
    TextView tvSpeed;
    TextView tvAlt;
    TextView tvTime;
    TextView tvProvider;
    String ProviderName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Get LocationManager to access the GPS data on your phone
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Who is the data provider? Built-in GPS receiver
            LocationProvider provider = lm.getProvider("gps");

            // Receive location updates from GPS receiver every minute, every 10m
            // Read the data using locationListener
            lm.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 60000, 1, locationListener);
            ProviderName = provider.getName();  
    }


    /** The LocationListener shows the most recent data with every call of onLocationChanged()() */
    private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    tvProvider = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ProviderText);
                    tvLong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.LonText);
                    tvLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.LatText);
                    tvSpeed = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.SpeedText);
                    tvAlt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.AltText);
                    tvTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TimeText);

                    tvProvider.setText(ProviderName);
                    tvLong.setText(Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()));
                    tvLat.setText(Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()));
                    tvSpeed.setText(Float.toString(loc.getSpeed()));
                    tvAlt.setText(Double.toString(loc.getAltitude()));
                    Date date = new Date(loc.getTime());
                    DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
                    tvTime.setText(dateFormat.format(date));
            }
            //Other methods of LocationListener are not needed, so add empty methods
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){}
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){}
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
    }
    public void onExitMenu(MenuItem menuItem)
    {
            finish();
    }
}
```

Here is my activity_main.xml file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/provider" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ProviderText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#0f0" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lat" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/LatText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#0f0"
    android:textSize="40.0sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/LonText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#0f0"
    android:textSize="40.0sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/speed" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/SpeedText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#0f0"
    android:textSize="40.0sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/alt" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/AltText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#0f0"
    android:textSize="40.0sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/time" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TimeText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#0f0"
    android:textSize="40.0sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my AndroidManifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >

</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
    </uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.gps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Worth a double check: 1/ device has GPS, 2/ GPS is enabled

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); no need to have this statement twice. U can always update your ui

Comment: You should look this library for location related stuff    https://github.com/nagendraksrivastava/Android-Location-Tracking-Library

Comment: @Sangeeta, please add a comment if any of the above solutions has worked for you. while permission "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" will get you GPS where as "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" will get you GPS co-ordinates i.e lat and long

Comment: Check that GPS is running.If GPS is running than you can see icon of that on actionbar of android device.Remember one thing GPS is mainly available when your device is in open sky.

Comment: Thanks. I did add the android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and then went outside and the program worked.